# SELECT in FROM-clause of another SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to modify an open source ERP for my job. It is developped in php / mysql.
Theres a feature that calculates the customers outstanding debt. (I don't know if its the correct term : it is the money the client has to pay for products he allready ordered and recieved)

In the customer class, the outstanding debt is calculed as follows :

```
SELECT ref_contact, SUM (outstanding_debt) outstanding_debt
FROM (SELECT ref_contact, MAX(including_tax_and_VAT_amout) outstanding_debt
      FROM (SELECT ref_contact, SUM(ROUND(qty * unit_price)
```

and it continues. But the part I don't understand is right there :
Its the SELECT statement with a SELECT in the FROM. I've never seen something like this. 
What does it means ?

Comment: One select statement will return a table. Select outer to that will do the selection from that table and so on..

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables My second answer pretty much covers what a select statement inside different parts of a query can do.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The title is a little broad, but the question itself looks legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are [sub queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html). Instead of using `SELECT [xyz] FROM [tablename]`, the sub query its result is used as "table" (data set).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) for detailed information on working with multiple tables in queries.